# How can I use an if statement on a select_tag in my model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

Okay so when I submit the form these are the parameters passed through my browser:

```
{"Search"=>"Job Letter and CD #",
"utf8"=>"✓",
"search"=>"g",
"commit"=>"Search"}
```

Basically what I need to do is in my model test the first parameter "Search".
Ex:

```
if Search == "Job Letter and CD #"
..do stuff..
elsif Search == "something else"
..do different stuff..
else
..do something..
```

I have been pounding my head over this and cant figure it out. My ruby code is below i may cut out some "end"'s and stuff like that to save room.

index.html.erb

```
<form class="well form-search right">
<%= select_tag "Search", options_for_select([ "Job Letter and CD #", "Date", "Cust",            "Job", "Date shipped", "Date billed", "Billed by" ], params[:search]) %>
<%= form_tag reports_path, :method => 'get' do %> 
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class=> "form-search", :align => "right" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", [ :JOBLETTER_CD_NUMBER, :DATE, :CUST, :JOB, :DATE_SHIPPED, :DATE_BILLED, :billed_by ] => nil, :class => "btn btn-success", :align => "right" %>
```

report.rb model

```
      def self.search(search)  
if Search == 'Job Letter and CD #'
  where('JOBLETTER_CD_NUMBER LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") 
elsif Search == 'Date'
  where('DATE ?', "%#{search}%")
else
  scoped  
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to pass 2 parameters to your search function present in the model

```
def self.search(what_to_search,search_string)
  if what_to_search == 'Job Letter and CD #'
     where('JOBLETTER_CD_NUMBER LIKE ?', "%#{search_string}%") 
  elsif what_to_search == 'Date'
     where('DATE ?', "%#{search_string}%")
  else
      scoped  
  end
end
```

And call search from your controller in this way

```
Search.search(params[:Search],params[:search])
```

Comment: Thanks when I changed my code it allowed me to search the job letter and cd # field but when i search a date it gives me this:                       ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "'%2012-07-30%'": syntax error): SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports"  WHERE (DATE '%2012-07-30%') LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

Comment: Nevermnd it was missing the LIKE. Thank you!